# Set color of text and change icon based on data text

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working with Angular/typescript and I am getting live data from base and ordering it in table.

My question is how can I change color of text and add different icon based of what do I get.
I got this

```
  <td>
      {{ item.status49 }}
   </td>
```

[In the end, I would like to have something like this][1] but of course as one or another

And I got 4 possible text status so If else will not work for me, I think

[image]

Comment: You should use `ngSwitch` directive (see https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[class]` and change dynamically:

```
<p [class]="visible ? 'green' : 'red'">
    Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

For Reference

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bbvwxr

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have 4 statuses :/ and im not sure how to implement 4 colors with this solution, im just a newbie

Comment: i have updated the code with 4 different classes please check again

Comment: Thank you! But I am not sure how to implement that to work, I have table with many data, and in column with Status I got 4 possible status (open, progress, closed, done) and I wanna do checking if displayed data (which is in {{item.status49}} is open to change color in table to lets say green and with thumb up icon, not by clicking or anything else, code will do it by itself

Comment: hi i have changed to a table view..hope this will meet your requirement

Comment: Thank you, coloring works! Even tho im not sure how to set diferent icons for different status, as you can see from the picture above

Comment: use can use fav icons as per the status changes

Comment: Hm... ok, you choose colors with class name and in css file, but where do you place 4 different icons, they cannot be placed in css somehow along with colors? I am using mat-icons, can it be done?

Comment: you can combine that with class name name we already have like `red material-icons add_alert`

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
<div *ngIf="condition1">
      your text + your icon
</div>
<div *ngIf="condition2">
      text2 + icon2
</div>
<div *ngIf="condition3">
      text3 + icon3
</div>
```

or you can use ng-container:

```
<td>
  <ng-container *ngIf="condition1"> your text + icon</ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="condition2"> your text + icon</ng-container>
...
</td>
```

or

```
<div [ngSwitch]="item.status49">
   <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'open'"> </ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'close'"></ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) , if I use ng-container how to I implement corectly condition to check if status is open then use this and that and if status is closed... Where do i go with my {{ item.status49 }} ?

Comment: As well, when I try last solution with [ngSwitch] like this   `     <div [ngSwitch]="item.status49">
                  <ng-container [ngSwitchCase]="open"> Something 1</ng-container>
                  <ng-container [ngSwitchCase]="close">Something 2</ng-container>
                </div>  `
I got an error :/

Comment: Sorry we need *ngSwitchCase="'open'"